# Editing a textbox using multi binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, multibinding

I have a textbox using multi binding. The fields used for this multi binding are properties coming from my data view model

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="FirstProperty" />
            <Binding Path="SecondProperty" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I would like to keep this behavior while allowing the user to update the content; I would then retrieve the content of the textbox in my data view model.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to edit a WPF textbox which uses multibinding and string.format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142583/how-to-edit-a-wpf-textbox-which-uses-multibinding-and-string-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the link that pangabiMC points to uses a converter I personally wouldn't myself, it's easier to both debug and unit test if you put this behaviour in the view model. Just create a separate property for your textbox (CombinedProperty) and keep it synced to the original properties:

```
public class YourViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _FirstProperty = "";
    public string FirstProperty
    {
        get { return this._FirstProperty; }
        set
        {
            this._FirstProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.FirstProperty);
            UpdateCombinedProperty();
        }
    }

    private string _SecondProperty = "";
    public string SecondProperty
    {
        get { return this._SecondProperty; }
        set
        {
            this._SecondProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SecondProperty);
            UpdateCombinedProperty();
        }
    }

    private string _CombinedProperty = "";
    public string CombinedProperty
    {
        get { return this._CombinedProperty; }
        set
        {
            this._CombinedProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CombinedProperty);
            UpdateSourceProperties();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCombinedProperty()
    {
        this.CombinedProperty = this.FirstProperty + " " + this.SecondProperty;
    }

    private void UpdateSourceProperties()
    {
        var fields = this.CombinedProperty.Split(' ');
        if (fields.Length != 2)
            return; // should handle validation properly
        this.FirstProperty = fields[0];
        this.SecondProperty = fields[1];
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Mark, I went ahead and humbly edited your reply, which works great in my case. Thanks for taking the team.

Comment: @Louitbol your edit is in the review queue, but it may not make it through due to the fact that you changed other code besides correcting the actual error. (Probably because of the edit length requirement?) If it is rejected, just comment the the necessary change so that Mark can fix it.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I believe it is due to the fact that I first edited without being signed in.

Comment: Well, my edit keeps getting rejected, dunno why as this code throws a SOE. Oh well...

Comment: Strange, didn't do it for me. Did your edit just include a check to see if value was different from the current value?